# symfony2 Object of class could not be converted to string

Tags: arrays, string, symfony, object, entity

I'm getting some strange error when creating a new user.

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Pr\UserBundle\Entity\Group could not be converted to string in /var/www/symfony/webprojekt/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Statement.php line 120
```

This happens, since I changed the choice "usergroup" into a single select for the reason that I don't want to allocate more than one usergroup (e.g. ROLE_USER) to a user.

I added the Entity of User and Group below, but I don't see any problem - I stuck again :(

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="sys_user")
*/
class User extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=8, nullable=true)
*/
protected $mobilepin;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
protected $client;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $client_id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=16383, nullable=true) //16383 = max varchar utf8
 */
private $imageurl;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)

 */
protected $firstname;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)

 */
protected $lastname;

    /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)

 */
protected $emailalert;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $phone;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable = true)


 */
protected $lock_state;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()(message="Check locations")
 */
private $locations;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $usergroups;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=5, options={"fixed" = true, "default" = "de_DE"})
   */
private $locale = 'de_DE';

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
 */
private $timezone = 'UTC';
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)

 */
private $created='1';
```

And the one from my group

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="user_group")
*/
class Group
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;



/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)

 */
protected $name;

    /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)

 */
protected $roles;
```

And at least how I create the choice:

```
->add('usergroups', 'entity', array('class' => 'PrUserBundle:Group','property' => 'name','required' => true, 'empty_value'    => 'Benutzergruppe','multiple'  => false, 'expanded'  => false))
```

It is weird :(

EDIT: if I change the "usergroups" from

```
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
```

to

```
 * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
```

it works fine. but then, the save data look like

```
O:26:"Pr\UserBundle\Entity\Group":3:{s:5:"
```

which looks very strange and wrong. I thought about saving the ID of the assigned group

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a relation between User and UserGroups you need to change the column definition from :

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
*/
private $usergroups;
```

to

```
/**
* @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
*/
private $usergroups;
```

and then define the reversed relation in groups:

```
Group {
    /**
    * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="User")
    */
    private $users;
```

You can read more about relations in doctrine here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html or here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations

Piotr

Answer (score 1):

Try to map 'usergroups' field in your User entity to Group entity instead of making it a string field.

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Group")
 * @JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $usergroups;
```

You may also view documentation about mappings here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#relationship-mapping-metadata
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#association-mapping

Comment: Thanks guys. NOw I get a noob-AnnotationException: [Semantical Error] The annotation "@ManyToOne" in property Pr\UserBundle\Entity\User::$usergroups was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation? :)

Comment: Add a use statement in Pr\UserBundle\Entity\User

"use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ManyToOne;"

Comment: ok. are there also use staements for JoinColumn? Ist the an overview what has to be included when using manyToMany and others?

Comment: you may do like so:
"use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;"
and then "@ORM\ManyToOne", "@ORM\JoinColumn" etc.

Comment: no still get that exception ... I'll check a few things and get back to you.